# How much did Queen Elizabeth I spend on her wardrobe over her reign?

Tags: england, royalty, fashion

Queen Elizabeth I of England had over 2000 expensive bejeweled gowns when she died. While she was thrifty by refurbishing her gowns when possible and giving some away to maids as payment what would she have spent on clothing over her 45-year reign?

Answer (score 3):

Not going to be able to give a good answer, but I wanted to capture some of the preliminary research I did.

caveat: I'm skeptical of any cost estimates. Between the sumptuary laws as a market distorting force, the difficulty of calculating inflation, and the difficulty of comparing private commercial transactions with government transactions (and the difficulty of figuring out which category each item of Elizabeth's wardrobe might best fit), any answer is going to be more useful for a method than a figure. (and the methodology would probably be a longish article, not a H:SE answer)

I'd love to have access to the sources behind this quote

> Although her wardrobe far outshone any other in the land, Elizabeth's clothing expenses were actually quite modest, compared to those of other royals--only a fifth of that spent by her successor King James, for example. [*ElizabethanCostume.net*](http://www.elizabethancostume.net/influence.html)

The Royal Museums at Greenwich support the notion that the figures are available, but don't provide a source.

> The cost of the Royal Wardrobe
> Detailed accounts of the Royal Wardrobe were kept. These records detail the types, amounts and cost of fabrics purchased, the suppliers used and the type of garment produced. At her death, over 2000 gowns were recorded in Elizabeth's wardrobe. These accounts and portraits of the period provide much of the available information about Elizabethan dress. *[rmg.co.uk](https://www.rmg.co.uk/stories/topics/elizabeth-royal-wardrobe)*

Support for the first figure comes from a rather pedestrian source

> Despite her lavish wardrobe, Elizabeth actually didn't spend that much of her budget on clothes, even spending just a fifth of what some of her male successors spent. Many of her clothes were gifts, and she also had existing dresses constantly restyled to look different by cutting off sleeves or adding embellishments. *[mental floss](https://www.mentalfloss.com/article/23718/quick-10-fashions-queen-elizabeth-i)*

[Queen Elizabeth I and the Power of Clothing](https://repository.wellesley.edu/islandora/object/ir%3A1004/datastream/PDF/download) doesn't answer the question but provides a bibliography that might be helpful in further research.  It does point out that significant parts of the wardrobe would have been donated rather than purchased, that the wardrobe served several state functions including foreign relations, sovereign legitimacy and patronage/employment support.

As noted above, the wardrobe included many gifts - I'm not sure how to include those in the cost model that OP requests

> Fortunately, Elizabeth didn't have to bear the staggering expense of her wardrobe completely on her own. As her reign continued, more and more people began bringing the Queen clothing as a New Year's present in an attempt to gain favor with her. There were dozens of stomachers, foreparts and sleeves given every year, often lavishly embroidered and breathtakingly decorated. In fact, Elizabeth's first pair of knitted silk stockings came to her as a gift on New Year's Day. She was so delighted with them that she immediately commissioned more to be made for her, and soon many courtiers of her court were beggaring themselves to afford the terribly fashionable, and terribly expensive, silk hose that the Queen was so fond of. *IBID: ElizabethanCostume.net*